# Expandable ListViewItem or how to avoid putting UI related properties into the business model

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, expand

I'm trying to build a small WPF application with a *listview* and some buttons. My goal is to dive deeper into *MVVM* and stuff.

The *listview* is bound to a collection of items in a viewmodel where each item has some properties like *name*, *id* etc. The datatemplate for this item type is able to expand and collapse (in terms of changing the height in a storyboard by clicking on a tiny arrow) in order to show/hide details on demand. That all works nicely, no problems.

Now what gives me headaches is how do I implement a button/command next to the *listview* that expands/collapses all items at once without mixing business with UI logic?

Sure, I could put a *IsExpanded* property into the item class, but this would violate MVVM/MVC as this would serve UI purposes and hence must not be in the model. So this is no real solution.

Do I need to have some *proxy* (UI-)item class that holds *IsExpanded* and contains a reference to the business object? If so how will this stay in sync with the collection in the viewmodel? This approach feels wrong or at least over the top to me.

I'd be happy if anyone could point to a better approach/solution. Any hint is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Killian

Comment: hint: you can have multiple view models.

Comment: hint: "some proxy (UI-)item class that holds IsExpanded and contains a reference to the business object" is called "view model"

Comment: *Do I need to have some proxy (UI-)item class that holds IsExpanded and contains a reference to the business object?* The proxy is known as a view model and this is a perfectly fine solution. What do you mean by "stay in sync with the collection in the viewmodel"?

Comment: The correct term is "MMMVMMVMMV" ("models and more models, viewmodels and more viewmodels, and many views") Your item viewmodel could be a wrapper around a reference to your item model, using a private reference to the model for backing fields for its INotifyPropertyChanged properties. Or it could be a duplicate which copies itself from an instance of the model, implements INotifyPropertyChanged with duplicate properties *plus UI-related properties*, and then has a method that returns a new model instance with state matching its own.

Comment: Another legitimate approach is to give your button a click handler, give the listview an x:Name property, and expand/collapse the ListViewItems directly in the click handler, without touching their DataContexts. Consider a case where you have the same collection displayed in two views: Maybe you want collapse in one view to be reflected in all other views of the same collection. If so, it's a viewmodel property. If you don't, it's just a view thing. MVVM doesn't mean "no view code"; it means "view code (usually not much) in the view, viewmodel code in the viewmodel, model code in the model".

Comment: Finally, your item viewmodel collection is what you bind to ItemsSource on the listview. On load, the main or parent viewmodel creates that collection from the models you've got and discard the models. On save, the parent/main vm creates a new model collection based on current viewmodel state, and saves that. No syncing.

Comment: I think Ed touched on this but... It's common to have properties like IsExpanded used by a view in a viewmodel. A fairly common approach is to have a row viewmodel which has all the properties you need to drive view stuff PLUS those of the model you are using for that view. You then copy data from model to row viewmodel and back again. The model is not exposed. Your viewmodel then can have validation stuff in there and whatnot and you can even potentially translate a model property from one type to another ( and back ).

Comment: Thanks @Andy for adding clarity to my remarks.

Comment: Thanks Ed and Andy. Your answers have been a great help.